# What is the difference between severity and priority? Which of these can be set through rules or API?

Tags: pagerduty

I see alerts and incidents having two attributes which sound similar:

- priority
- severity

What is the difference between them? How are they set?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alerts in PagerDuty can be generated with a severity field. These severity values can be directly provided from the triggering monitoring tool, or set using event rules.
When an incident is generated from an alert, the alert’s severity field is used to determine the urgency level. The values of this field must be one of the following: critical, error, warning, or info.

More info here: https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/dynamic-notifications#eventalert-severity-levels

More information on Priority: https://support.pagerduty.com/docs/incident-priority